# Concat string in mutliple rows with php/mysql or codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, concatenation

I would like to concat the same value to a field on multiple rows with a constraint..

With php/mysql, i'll do something like that:

```
$newdata = '33';

$sql = 'UPDATE users set relation=concat(relation,$newdata) 
       WHERE user_id IN (22, 31, 54)';
```

When the relation field is empty, this query is ok, but if the field is not empty (f.e relation:'8,56,78') i would like to concat ',33' with the coma in addition.

Have you an idea of how to do this without using multiple queries?
I'd like to know if there is a way to do this in codeigniter too.

Thank you !

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: That is a TRUELY BAD way to hold relationships! Use a cross reference table instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL has IF-Statements:

```
"UPDATE users set relation= 
    CASE WHEN relation = '' 
        THEN $newdata 
        ELSE concat(relation,$newdata) 
    END
 WHERE user_id IN (22, 31, 54);"
```

Answer (score 1):

try this query, if field will not have data than it will work in that case as well

```
$newdata = '33';

UPDATE users set relation = IFNULL (CONCAT( relation , $newdata ), $newdata) WHERE user_id IN (22, 31, 54)
```